# How does the Feature Gate system work on solana core?

Tags: development, version

When looking at the Solana github repo, it seems that the devs follow some sort of feature gating system for releasing new features ([example](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31273)). It seems there's always a `Minimum Beta Version`, `Minimum Stable Version`, and a few other fields. What do these means exactly?

For example, if the `Minimum Beta Version` is 1.17, and the currently running Solana version is 1.17, does this mean this feature is live already or do I have to wait for the `Minimum Stable Version` (or something else altogether)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can follow the feature activation schedule here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/wiki/Feature-Gate-Activation-Schedule

The feature flags are accounts which get activated.
Feature gates get activated on epoch boundaries and will be activated first on test net, then dev net and then finally mainnet.
On the list you can also see the owners of each feature gate.